# Width and height using camera are not the same as size using libgdx

Tags: android, camera, libgdx, width, screen

Width and height,  of the blue areas using camera,  are not the same as size using libgdx. as you can see in the attached screenshot i want to display the Texture having same horizontal and vertical dimensions.

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(300, 300 * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth()));
```

How can I achieve same width and height?

[image]

Comment: Use screen or fit viewport, take a look at [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)

Comment: Same width and height as what? You want to stretch an arbitrary image to fit the screen?